# SByte (signed) is 16bit not 8bit for sbyte min value

Tags: windows, powershell

I try to understand why 16bit and not only 8bit for SByte type (AKA:signed char).

```
$base = 2   

# 8-bit (char et unsigned char)

$("byte   : " + [byte]::MinValue.ToString() + " to " + [byte]::MaxValue.ToString())
$bin = [Convert]::ToString([byte]::MaxValue, $base).PadLeft(8, "0")
$($bin.Length.ToString() + "," + $bin)
$bin = [Convert]::ToString([byte]::MinValue, $base).PadLeft(8, "0")
$($bin.Length.ToString() + "," + $bin)

$("sbyte  : " + [sbyte]::MinValue.ToString() + " to " + [sbyte]::MaxValue.ToString())
$bin = [Convert]::ToString([sbyte]::MaxValue, $base).PadLeft(8, "0")
$($bin.Length.ToString() + "," + $bin)
$bin = [Convert]::ToString([sbyte]::MinValue, $base).PadLeft(8, "0")
$($bin.Length.ToString() + "," + $bin)
```

Output:

```
sbyte  : -128 to 127 (signed 8bit)
01111111
0x7f
1111111110000000
0xff80
```

If this is due to a two's complement, this is my operating system or hardware level?

Comment: I really don't understand your question. Is it possible to rewrite it in proper English (as a not to others : English also isn't my native language)? I did some checking on the data types, but a [sbyte]::maxvalue returns 127 (and the minvalue is -128) which seems normal for an Sbyte. Keep in mind that Powershell does an automatic typecast if the data doesn't fit (so if you have a unsigned byte value of 255 and add 1 it won't overflow to 0 but it actually casts the data to an 32 bit int)

Comment: There are no `[Convert]::ToString([sbyte], [int])` overload. Closest match is `[Convert]::ToString([int16], [int])`. And, BTW, `[char]` in .NET is 16-bit wide and does not have signed variant.

Comment: @PetSerAl , everything is explained then. thank's I see that

Comment: @bluuf , I have an 8bit signed  char with an output of 16 bit length. Why not 8bit ?

Comment: Please do not edit answers into your question.